# Uploading Base64 Image to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="placeholder.png" runat="server" ID="plhdr" />
```

The webpage lets a user upload an image, which is processed through a JavaScript library and then set as the source of the above control. The JavaScript sets the source as a Base64 String like this:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...

I have a function on the same page that is meant to upload the displayed image to Azure Storage and then add a reference to it in Azure SQL. The code I have in the code behind is:

```
    StorageCredentials creden = new StorageCredentials(accountname, accesskey);
    CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creden, useHttps: true);
    CloudBlobClient client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer cont = client.GetContainerReference("testcont");
    cont.CreateIfNotExists();
    cont.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
    {
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
    });
    CloudBlockBlob cblob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference("cblob");

    var imagesrc = plhdr.ImageUrl;

    cblob.UploadFromFile(@imagesrc);

    var imageUrl = cblob.Uri;
```

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\Windows\system32\placeholder.png'. Exception Details:
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'D:\Windows\system32\dist\img\fling\space.gif'.

At this line: `cblob.UploadFromFile(@imagesrc);`.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How are passing the image content to your server side code?

Comment: @GauravMantri sorry, how do I do this?

Comment: I have not used this in ages but there should be some control which should upload the file to the server. See this for example: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2011/01/20/uploading-image-to-a-folder-and-display-the-image-after.aspx.

Comment: I can't use that because that deals with a File Upload, I need to be able to save something like "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ..." as an image file.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing and might need more code. Are you saying that you are uploading a file from browser to server filesystem, then from server filesystem to Azure storage?

Comment: Sorry about that. The user uploads a file onto the webpage, where a JavaScript function processes it and displays the image (nothing is stored yet). The image source is set as a Base64 string, and I need to grab that source value from the element and save it as an image file to Azure Storage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to your description, we can upload the image file to azure storage by using `UploadFromStream(stream)`, Please have a try to do it with following sample code. It works for me.

```
  CloudBlockBlob cblob = cont.GetBlockBlobReference("testblob");
  var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");// without data:image/jpeg;base64 prefix, just base64 string
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
  {
     cblob.UploadFromStream(stream);
  }
```

Comment: This solved it - thanks. I also had to delay the method because it was firing before the element was updated by the JavaScript.